# NSOrderedSet wont build in iPhone class generated by XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, xcode4

I created a simple data model with a 1-many relationship in XCode 4.1 on Lion.

The type of the property generated for this relationship is NSOrderedSet, which fails to compile because the type is unknown.

I searched the documentation to learn that this is a new kind of collection classes added for Mac OS 10.7 (Lion), especially useful in managed objects (I'm just getting used to the way Apple works: something as basic as a collection type in the language is bound to an OS release... interesting)

This makes sense, NdOrderedSet is apparently a combination of the features of NSSet and NSArray - that is, it has an indexed order like an array, with each element unique like a set. Nice. But, my questions are:

1. Why won't it compile?
2. Why is XCode generating something that won't compile?

   I'm going to take a swag at #1 myself: My SDK is iOS 4.3, which predates Lion (and is not Mac OS but iOS) and simply does not have this new collection class.
   okay, fair enough, but #2 stands: why did XCode generate it for me? Why not detect my SDK and generate something that works? Why not give me a choice?

   This brings me to #3 and #4
3. What's the workaround? Should I change it to NSSet or NSArray? How did XCode generate these things before 4.0?
4. If I were to use NSOrderedSet (ie get it to work somehow) would it be backward compatible with prior iOS versions?

Answer (score 1):

Core Data ordered relationships are only available on iOS 5, not iOS 4.3.
You need the iOS 5 SDK which is only available on Xcode 4.2. Switch from Xcode 4.1 to Xcode 4.2 and you should be fine.

3: the workaround is to use Xcode 4.2 and to target iOS 5. If you still want to target iOS 4.x and have ordered relationship, read on.

4: you are unlikely to be able to get NSOrderedSet to work in iOS 4.3. The class is simply missing from Cocoa Touch. So you would need to reeimplement it from scratch, which is definitely doable. What is *not* doable, is to then get Core Data to use it. So forget it.

Now, it may be worth mentioning that it *is* possible to define ordered relationships with the "old" Core Data. It requires a bit more work, but it's definitely doable. Here is an example:

Imagine a `Meal` and a `Course` entities. A meal has an ordered relationship to courses, as courses during a meal come up in a specific order. You don't want to eat your dessert before the main course!

The idea is to define a third helper entity that represents the course membership in the meal. Let's call that entity `CourseInMeal`. Now set up the following relationships:

```
Course <--------->> CourseInMeal <<----------> Meal
```

Where the double arrow represents the "to-many" end of the relationships.

These relationships basically says that a Course can be present in several meals, and that a Meal can have several courses.

The only remaining this is to represent the **ordered** relationship. To do so, simply add an attribute to the `CourseInMeal` entity, perhaps called `position`.

Now when you want to define a new meal you create a new instance of `CourseInMeal` for each course in the meal, with something like:

```
CourseInMeal *newMealMembership = [CourseInMeal insertInManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
newMealMembership.course = myDessert;
newMealMembership.meal = myBirthdayMeal;
newMealMembership.position = 3; // or whatever
[self.moc save:NULL];
```

Voilà, you have an ordered relationship in plain old Core Data.

Comment: Thanks - that answers #1, but not #2: Since I'm using XCode 4.1 with iOS SDK 4.3, why does XCode generate this?
And if I were to upgrade to 4.2, iOS 5, does this mean XCode is generating ManagedObject subclasses that, by default, will not be backward compatible with iOS 4?

Comment: This is because ordered relationships *are* supported by Xcode 4.1, only for running under MacOS X Lion. As often, tools expect runtime support. Here, runtime support is available from the Mac SDK, not the iOS SDK. Of course you can think it would be a good thing for the **tool** to report a problem with the **SDK**, but such cross-checks are expensive and brittle. Since you still get an error diagnostic, albeit slightly later from the SDK, this is good enough.

Comment: Another way to look at it, is that the Xcode Core Data Editor does its job: generate a model and associated source code. It does't want to know (and maybe even can't know) what you are going to do with it: use it with a compatible SDK or not.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers. That is another way to look at it, but I find it a slightly apologistic way. This is not a compiler or a commandline tool at work here - it's a code generator in a high level wizard in XCode. It ought to try to generate code that compiles in the current environment, imo. But I won't argue that point because it's vague and this will end up like usenet. For arguments sake, say it _shouldnt_ try to work out the environment. Nonetheless, knowing that the default type wont compile in iOS or 10.6 it should _at least_ offer an option in the wizard with a warning

Comment: I kind of agree... though I can see why this feature is not yet in Xcode 4 with everything else that's missing or buggy in there.

Comment: I'm ready to accept this as the final answer - since it answers #1, and I can see now the answer to #2 is "bug in XCode 4" and the answer to #4 is "no, backward compatibility is lost", but I'm still not sure of the answer to #3. Mundi below says NSSet, but since a set is not ordered, how does it maintain the order if you load and persist. Can anyone try this with Xcode 3 and tell me?

Comment: It *is* an NSSet. Core Data does not support ordered relationship for iOS 4.3. The relationship you will get is *unordered*, thus the NSSet. Regarding a workaround, there is none, depending on what you mean by "workaround". However there *is* a solution. See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it out. Mine comes out as a `NSSet`, not `NSOrderedSet`.

Perhaps you should check your project settings, specifically the items under the heading Architecture. (Select Project, Build Settings, **Architectures** and **Base SDK**, as well as Supported Platforms).

Comment: Here's a copy/paste of that section of the project settings:
Basically its iOS 4.3 SDK in XCode 4.1. Is that what you're using when you get NSSet? Also is your relationship ordered? (You have to check the "ordered" flag in the OM editor - it's not ordered by default - which would result in NSSet being used)  

ADDITIONAL_SDKS = ARCHS = $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)  
SDKROOT = iphoneos  
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO  
SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS = iphonesimulator iphoneos  
VALID_ARCHS = armv6 armv7