# NSOrderedSet for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

For some odd reason NSOrderedSet does not appear to be implemented in iOS.  Is there another object that gives similar functionality -- basically the ability to insert/remove objects randomly and access the first/last in sort order?

It seems to me that something like this would be needed in order to implement basic FIFO queues and the like.

**Edit:** I ended up doing an RYO solution.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392019/nsorderedset-wont-build-in-iphone-class-generated-by-xcode for info

Comment: It seems to be arriving with iOS 5. http://gravityjack.com/gravityjack_news/ios-5-for-developers-what-you-need-to-know.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is this open source data structures library:
http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/index.html

In that library is a CHOrderedSet
http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/interface_c_h_ordered_set.html

It's only dependency is NSMutableSet so it should work across all your iOS versions.

EDIT:

As Bourne pointed out above, it's also in iOS5 ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW34)):

> The new `NSOrderedSet` collection class offers the semantics of sets,
>   whereby each element occurs at most once in the collection, but where
>   elements are in a specific order.

CHOrderedSet is a good option if you don't have a hard dependency on iOS5.

Answer (score -2):

NSOrderedSet and NSMutableOrderedSet are not available in iOS 5. Here's the reference for anyone curious:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableOrderedSet

Comment: your link proves they ARE available in iOS5